# Basic solving for fractions

Tags: fractions

Can someone help me with this? I am a beginner to physics and in a question i need no isolate a constant to solve for another one.

A/B=C/D solve for D step by step please.

Comment: Your question is not clear..

Comment: This is not a question for Mathematics. It is a very very basic question. We can ask that to a friend.

Comment: If it's so easy, answering it shouldn't be such a big task??? @AlexSilva

Comment: $D$ downstairs is no good. Multiply both sides of the equation by $D$:  $D\cdot{A\over B}=D\cdot {C\over D}\Rightarrow D\cdot{A\over B}=C$.   Now multiply both sides by ${B\over A}$.

Comment: @David Mitra, you have to be careful when multiplying both sides by $\frac{B}{A}$, because $A$ can be $0$

Comment: @Mathi Of course. I forgot to mention that, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

We start with $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}$.

Our goal is to isolate $D$. (Of course since $B$ and $D$ are in the denominator, they are assumed to be non-zero).

First we want to get $D$ into the numerator. We multiply both sides by $D$.

$\frac{AD}{B}=C$

Now we multiply both sides by $B$.

$AD=BC$.

Lastly, we divide both sides by $A$ (once again, this assumes that $A$ is non-zero).

We get that $D=\frac{BC}{A}$

Comment: What will happen if $A$ is $0$?

Comment: @Mathi: If $A=0$, then our first equation simplifies to $0=\frac{C}{D}$. Then $D$ can take on any (nonzero) value as long as $C=0$. If $C$  is non-zero, then there is no solution.